# Combine source's output into stream

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'd like a conduit that takes a source as an argument and uses the latter's output combined with its own. In types, something like e.g.

```
combine :: ConduitM () Int m ()
        -> ConduitM Int (Int, Int) m ()
```

where I'd hope that the following

```
runConduit $ yieldMany [(1::Int)..]
          .| combine (yieldMany [100..])
          .| takeC 5
          .| sinkList
```

gives

```
[(1,100), (2,102), (3,103), (4,104), (5, 105)]
```

This is a simplified version of my use case. But I'm not sure how to go about this beyond

```
combine source = mapC $ \i -> do
  -- stream output from source somehow
  (i, i)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [ZipSource](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.0/conduit-1.2.12.1/Data-Conduit.html#t:ZipSource), which may look like this in your case:

```
getZipSource $ (,)
    <$> ZipSource (yieldMany [1..])
    <*> ZipSource (yieldMany [100..])
```